# How do you kick off a js function on expansion of an aria-expanded div in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion that I have implemented using aria-expanded in my AngularJS app. It looks as follows:

```html
<div aria-controls="something_{{$id}}" aria-expanded="false" 
     ng-click="vm.myFunction()" class="expansion-panel-toggler collapsed" 
     data-target="#something_{{$id}}" data-toggle="collapse" 
     id="something_header_{{$id}}" role="button">
```

As you can see there is a controller function that is kicked off when the accordion is clicked. This is not an ideal solution. It works ok because the function is kicked off when the the accordion is clicked (and thus expanded), but I don't like it for the following two reasons:

1. I only want the function to execute when the accordion is expanded, and the current solution will execute the function on both expansion and collapse
2. By having the function execute on-click, the relationship between the accordion expansion and the function is indirect. I would rather have it directly detecting the expansion of the accordion rather than the click.

Is this easy to do while still using aria-expanded?

Comment: @georgeawg I believe aria-expanded is part of bootstrap

Comment: The `bootstrap.js` library does not play well with the `angular.js` library. It would be better to write your own directive or use [Angular-UI Bootstrap Accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!accordion)

Comment: @B.Smith If you're going to use this directive (aria-expanded is not bootstrap specific BTW), then you're stuck with using ng-click. However note you can easily enough track the expanded or unexpanded state of the div with some field on `vm` and write `ng-click="!vm.expanded && vm.myFunction()"`.